# What is the line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ whose transition function is $e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let $U_0,U_\infty$ be the two affine patches of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$, neighborhoods of "0" and "$\infty$" respectively. Let $L$ be the line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ constructed by gluing the trivial bundles over $U_0$ and $U_\infty$ via the function $e^z$, which is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function on $U_0\cap U_\infty$.

I've never taken complex geometry (my background is in algebraic geometry, and $e^z$ isn't an algebraic function), so my question is - does $L$ exist in the algebraic world? Which one is it? (for which $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is $L\cong\mathcal{O}(n)$?). If it isn't any of them, what is the "right statement" to say that it doesn't exist? For example, is $e^z$ somehow not in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(U_0\cap U_\infty)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topologically there are $\Bbb Z$-many line bundles, determined by the first Chern class, and one can calculate this by calculating what element of $\pi_1 \Bbb C^*$ the transition function represents. So it suffices to see how $e^z$ winds around $0$ as $z$ winds once counterclockwise around zero. But the very fact that $e^z$ extends to all of $\Bbb C$ means that this winding number is *zero*. So you've (topologically!) given the trivial line bundle. If I remember my Riemann surfaces, for $\Bbb P^1$, each complex line bundle has one and only one holomorphic structure up to isomorphism (because $H^i(\Bbb P^n,\mathcal O)=0$ for $i>0$, yes?) - so you've just written down the trivial line bundle.

Comment: I believe you! I just have problems wrapping my head around the consequence that the $n$-fold zero (resp. pole) of the transition function $z^n$ at $z=0$ (resp. at $\infty$) give $L\cong \mathcal{O}(n)$, but $e^z$ *with its essential singularity at $\infty$* gives something trivial :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: The trick is that 0 and $\infty$ don't really matter - just $|z|=1$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for your answer! I'm not very familiar with Chern classes, (or classical differential geometry), so the article on wikipedia seemed rather opaque to me. When the transitiion functions are algebraic (restrictions of globally meromorphic functions), I've been using Cech cohomology relative to the cover $U_0,U_\infty$ to understand the classification of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$. So my question is - can you elaborate on how I should think about Chern classes? Specifically, how to calculate them? Alternatively, can one use Cech cohomology to understand this bundle $L$?

Comment: @oxeimon: The first chern class is much easier than the rest. In the sheaf cohomology long exact sequence $H^1(X,\mathcal O) \to H^1(X,\mathcal O^*) \to H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$, the last map is $E \mapsto c_1(E)$. In terms of actually calculating, I think in terms of that transition function - this is actually very special to $\Bbb P^1$, because we can explicitly write down all line bundles this way. The point is that the line bundle is the same topologically even if you homotope the transition map $U_0 \cap U_\infty \to \Bbb C^*$, so that the line bundle is determined...

Comment: ...by the homotopy class of this map, which is to say is determined by the element of $\pi_1(\Bbb C^*)$ it represents. The connection to Chern classes is that this is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, and an explicit calculation (with the differential geometry definition, if you like) shows that the line bundle corresponding to $n \in \pi_1(\Bbb C^*)$ has first Chern class $n \in \Bbb Z \cong H^2(\Bbb P^1,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Okay so I actually convinced myself that $L$ is trivial, by comparing its descent datum to the trivial descent datum. Now I'd like to see this via sheaf cohomology as you suggested. When computing sheaf cohomology in algebraic geometry, it suffices to use Cech cohomology on an affine open cover. Does the same work in this complex analytic situation, or will I need to use a better open cover?

Comment: @oxeimon: You want an acyclic open cover (so $H^i(U,\mathcal F)=0$ for any of the open sets or their intersections. For $U=\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb C^*$ and $\mathcal F=\mathcal O$ or $\mathcal O^*$, I think this should follow from a version of the Poincaré lemma. I don't have my copy of Griffiths and Harris with me right now but they do this computation near the end of 0.3, their section on sheaf cohomology.

Answer (score 2):

Since $e^z$ extends as a non-zero function over $U_0$, you can change basis on $U_0$ so that your gluing function is now just $1$.  This makes it clear that you have the trivial bundle.

(Incidentally, by GAGA, any holomorphic line bundle on $\mathbb P^1$ has to be algebraic, so what you wrote down had to be $\mathscr O(n)$ for *some* $n$.)

Comment: Excellent: +1. The wonderfully elementary  answer here simply says that the holomorphic cocycle $g_{01}=e^z$ is a holomorphic coboundary:  $g_{01}=\frac {g_0}{g_1}=   \frac {e^z}{1} $ with $g_i\in \mathcal O^*(U_i)$, so that the associated holomorphic bundle is trivial, and thus is the underlying holomorphic bundle of the trivial algebraic line bundle.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice way to describe it.